# How to allow an EB to access a S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to access (read/write) a S3 bucket from an Elastic Beanstalk instance.

I have read AWS documentation to configure the bucket policy but I still have an access denied error.

Below is my bucket policy :

[image]
When I try to put an object, I can this error :

```
{ AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
```

Comment: I would delete the bucket policy and add an IAM role to the EB EC2 instances that has permission to access the bucket.

Comment: good point. I have set permission en EB EC2 role as an inline policy ans it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the bucket policy and add the IAM role to the EB EC2 instances which has permission to S3 Bucket access.